# invert place of the UIView, with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm looking for the best way to invert the place of two `UIView`, with animation if possible (first i need to change the place, animation is optionnal).

**viewController** :

[image: image view]

So, i want `view1` to invert his place with the `view2`. The `views` are set with autolayout in the storyboard at the init.

```
if state == true {
    view1 at the top
    view2 at the bot
} else {
    view 2 at the top
    view 1 at the top
}
```

I've tried to take `view.frame.(x, y, width, height)` from the other view and set it to the view but it doesn't work.

Comment: are the view sizes the same all the time or they are dynamic ?

Comment: @John question is important, If the view are the same size, maybe you could use table view instead of different views.  and then just animate Rows.

Comment: @John They are dynamic, height is proportional to the superView. View1 is top constraint to the header, and view2 top constraint to the View1. I think i have to change it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to have a topConstraint for both views connected to the header and then change their values and animate the transition. You can do it in a way similar to this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

 var view1TopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 var view2TopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   view1TopConstraint = view1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(header.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    view1TopConstraint.isActive = true

  view2TopConstraint = view2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(header.bottomAnchor, constant: view1.frame.height)
    view2TopConstraint.isActive = true
}

func changeView2ToTop() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { //this will animate the change between 2 and 1 where 2 is at the top now
    self.view2TopConstraint.constant = 0
    self.view1TopConstraint.constant = view2.frame.height
    //or knowing that view2.frame.height represents 30% of the total view frame you can do like this as well
    //      self.view1TopConstraint.constant = view.frame.height * 0.3

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }) 
 }
```

You could also create the NSLayoutConstraint in storyboard and have an outlet instead of the variable I have created or set the top constraint for both views in storyboard at "remove at build time" if you are doing both. This way you won't have 2 top constraints and no constraint warrning

Comment: This make my view 2 correctly set to the header  but view1 disappear

Comment: make sure the view2.frame.height is set when you run the function. If you already know the proportion you should try to replace it with the proportion. I will edit the response with how you can replace it with proportion

Comment: I think is that make some conflict in the constraint, cause i've in the debugger : UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints  warning

Comment: how do you add the constrains from storyboard or like i did ? if it is like it did look the top constrain for both views in storyboard and tick remove at build time

Comment: Both, but i set priority to 999 in my storyboard

Comment: the thing is that if you set the constrains in storyboard and not mark the top one as remove at build time and do the rest as I did this will make you have 2 top Contrains for the view which causes a conflict (it will not know which constraint to actually use and just break a random one / the reason why the view1 is hidden because it is still under view2)

Comment: Problem solved, a big thank's to you for your help and your time !

Answer (score 0):

I Made an Example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24078452/MovingView.zip

I just created a Storyboard with 3 View, Header, View 1 (Red) and View 2 (Yellow). Then I added IBoutlets and animated them at viewDid Appear, here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var position1: CGRect?
    var position2: CGRect?

    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        position1 = view1.frame
        position2 = view2.frame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5) {
            self.view1.frame = self.position2!
            self.view2.frame = self.position1!
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello @Makaille I have try to resolve your problem.
I have made an example, which will help you for your required implementation.
Check here: [Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sy8uwg3hys4wx8e/AnimationOfTwoViews.zip?dl=0)

I hope, it will going to help you.

```
@IBAction func toggle(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    if(sender.isSelected){
        let topPinConstantValue = layout_view2TopPin.constant
        layout_view1TopPin.constant = topPinConstantValue
        layout_view2TopPin.priority = 249
        layout_view1BottomPin_to_View2Top.priority = 999

        layout_view1TopPin.priority = 999
        layout_view2BottomPin_ToView1Top.priority = 249

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (value) in
            if(value){
                sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        })

    } else {
        let topPinConstantValue = layout_view1TopPin.constant
        layout_view2TopPin.constant = topPinConstantValue
        layout_view1TopPin.priority = 249
        layout_view2BottomPin_ToView1Top.priority = 999

        layout_view2TopPin.priority = 999
        layout_view1BottomPin_to_View2Top.priority = 249

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (value) in
                if(value){
                    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                }
        })
    }

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your time, i'm not using bottom constraint cause i've proportional height i'll try to adapt it, it's look like great. Just one question, why priority to 249 ? is it just be random to be low ?

Comment: Because when we want to change the priorities at runtime we have to set 250 to 249 and 1000 to 999, otherwise we will have issue.